# Limits and formalizing the solution

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I have the following limit and I needed to check whether it exists and, if it does, determine it.

$\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{x}$.
I have come to the following solution - and it'd be great if someone would look over it; I am especially unsure whether my solution is formal enough. It's as if I have the right idea, yet I still have some issues with formalizing these notions, putting, if you will, in the right language. So this, then, would be the solution:

$-1 \ge sin(x) \ge 1 \forall x$
$ \implies (-1 \ge sin(x) \ge 1) \cdot \frac{1}{\left\lvert x \right\rvert} = -\frac{1}{\left\lvert x \right\rvert} \ge sin(x) \ge \frac{1}{\left\lvert x \right\rvert}$

$\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} -\frac{1}{\left\lvert x \right\rvert}=0$
$\land \lim \limits_{x \to -\infty}\frac{1}{\left\lvert x \right\rvert} \implies$
$\lim \limits_{x \to -\infty} \frac{sin(x)}{x}=0$ Therefore, this limit does not exist.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Therefore, this limit does not exist." -- ... did you not just conclude that the limit is zero, and therefore the limit exists?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just write $\frac{1}{x}\leq \frac{sin(x)}{x}\leq-\frac{1}{x}$ (because $x$ is negative). Then you just let the limit do its job. Since the two limits on left and right are 0, by ***squeeze theorem*** you get that your desired limit is also equal to 0.
\begin{equation} EDIT \end{equation}
By this principle, you can conclude that
\begin{equation}
(something\ limited)\times(something \ that\ tends\ to\ 0)\rightarrow 0
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it!